# heroku and amazon s3 image resizing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, heroku, paperclip

my app lives on heroku, and I have recently made some changes to the architecture.  specifically the size of the images in users profiles has changed. like so:

```
//images.rb

has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {:full =>"800x800>"},
:storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml", :path => ':id/:style'

//images_old.rb
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => {:full =>"600x600>"},
:storage => :s3, :s3_credentials => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/s3.yml", :path => ':id/:style'
```

Is there any way I can update the size of the images that the users have already uploaded (this is a live app)?

Comment: delayed_job, workers, and custom scripting. Or just ignore the 200px difference

Comment: Why convert 600x600 to 800x800 ? Won't that cause the up-sized image to look "bad" ?